# C# sql create one connection and open and close for each query

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I recently inherited a C# Web app that creates a new connection for every query like so:

```
public class QueryForm
{
    public bool getStudents()
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn"].ConnectionString);
        conn.Open();
        //commands
        conn.Close();
    }

    protected void getProfessors()
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn"].ConnectionString);
        conn.Open();
        //Commands
        conn.Close();
    }


    protected void getProfessors()
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn"].ConnectionString);
        conn.Open();
        //Commands
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

I understand that this is typically the best way to do it, but is it acceptable or "best practice" to have the constructor create the connection object, and then have each method/Query open and then close that connection like so:

```
public class QueryForm
{
    SqlConnection conn;

    public QueryForm()
    {
        conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn"].ConnectionString);
    }

    public bool getStudents()
    {
        conn.Open();
        //commands
        conn.Close();
    }

    protected void getProfessors()
    {
        conn.Open();
        //Commands
        conn.Close();
    }

    protected void getCourses()
    {
        conn.Open();
        //Commands
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

I prefer the second way as it does not make multiple connection objects. However, the first way would also be preferable if I were to make the methods and class static.

Comment: You may want to check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/861552/when-should-i-open-and-close-a-connection-to-sql-server?rq=1

Comment: @Gonzalo -- In reference to that article, this poster is not mentioning making the SqlConnection static, only the methods and class.

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: @Oluwafemi "is it acceptable or "best practice" to have the constructor create the connection object, and then have each method/Query open and then close that connection"

Comment: I see. sorry so sleepy...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Either one of these are acceptable.  A `SqlConnection` uses a connection-pool so it shouldn't affect performance much.  Having multiple `SqlConnection` objects isn't going to hurt anything.  This comes down to a preference.

I would suggest encapsulating the commands in a `using` statement if you keep the connections inside the methods, such as:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(...))
{
    conn.Open();
    //commands
    conn.Close();
}
```

This ensures proper disposal of the connection.

Comment: The `using` statement means you don't need the `.Close()`. [When the connection is disposed it is closed.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.close(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Yes but it doesn't hurt, and makes me feel warm and fuzzy inside :-)

Answer (score 1):

It is important that you keep the connection open for the **shortest possible time**.
SQL connection is using a [connection pool](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca(v=vs.110).aspx) so opening a connection actually reuses a connection behind the scenes.
If you keep the connection open your at risk of running into error: 'Parallel transactions are not supported' if you use the method [BeginTransaction](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8aht5dh7(v=vs.110).aspx).

This being a web app with a potentially large number of connections, 
leaving the connection object open longer puts you in risk of exhausting the connection pool and getting: 'The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool' error.

Additionally, you must make sure the connection is closed even if an exception is thrown.

This should be done with a using block like:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(...))
{
    conn.Open();
    //commands
}
```

since exiting a 'using' block calls .Dispose() on the used object.

or with a try / catch / finally block like:

```
SqlConnection conn = null;

try
{
    conn = new SqlConnection(...);    
    conn.Open();
    //commands
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    ...
}
finally
{
    if(conn != null)
        conn.Close();
}
```

Comment: The remark regarding the exceptions is incorrect. A using block ensures that Dispose is called on the object even if an exception is thrown. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/yh598w02(v=vs.100)