# Handling Database Connection in C#

Tags: c#, sqlconnection

I am Creating WinForm application using C# and SqlServer. I have to handle many database CRUD Queries on it. And also there are so many forms and so many controllers.

Now I want to know is, If i create common class for handle database connectivity with many methods for open connection, close connection, execute Sql command or do any other data retrievals. This method is good or bad?

or below method for run every query is good or bad?

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=MYDB"))  
{  
    connection.Open();        
    // Pool A is created.  
}
```

which method is better for performance and security?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# sql create one connection and open and close for each query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31301634/c-sharp-sql-create-one-connection-and-open-and-close-for-each-query)

Comment: Have a look at Entity Framework, `DbContext`, `Database` classes

Comment: What kind of solution?

Comment: @John no i'm talking about this kind of solution https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/f26fb0/connection-class-in-C-Sharp/

Comment: And does the duplicate not answer your question?

Comment: @Dmitry I dont want to Entity Framework.

Comment: @John No. i try to create external Connection Class and create object from it and use it's methods when I needed. is it good or bad

Comment: So [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31303599/3181933) from the duplicate doesn't answer your question? Why not? What's wrong with it?

Comment: You might want to check out Dapper. A micro-ORM built for speed. That's my personal choice these days.

Comment: @Zohar thank you for your suggestion. I will consider about that.

Answer (score 4):

Here are some points to think about when using a connection.

1) Dispose the connection object as soon as you no longer need it by using the using statement:

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionstring))  
{  
    // your sql magic goes here
}
```

2) If you're not disposing the object immediately, you can make sure the connection is closed using a try-finally statement:

```
var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);
try
{
// do sql shizzle
}
finally
{
    conn.Close();
}
```

3) To prevent SQL injection, use parameterized queries, never concatenated strings

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionstring))  
{  
    conn.Open();
    using(var comm = new SqlCommand("select * from FooBar where foo = @foo", conn))
    {
        comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@foo", "bar"));
        // also possible:
        // comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@foo", "bar");
        using(var reader = comm.ExecuteReader())
        {
            // Do stuff with the reader;
        }
    }
}
```

4) If you're performing multiple update, insert or delete statements, and they all need to be succesful at once, use a transaction:

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionstring))  
{  
    conn.Open();
    using(var trans = conn.BeginTransaction())
    {
        try 
        {
            using(var comm = new SqlCommand("delete from FooBar where fooId = @foo", conn, trans))
            {
                comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@foo", DbType = System.Data.DbType.Int32 });
                for(int i = 0; i < 10 ; i++)
                {
                    comm.Parameters["@foo"].Value = i;
                    comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
            trans.Commit();
        }
        catch (Exception exe)
        {
            trans.Rollback();
            // do some logging
        }
    }
}
```

5) Stored procedures are used similarly:

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionstring))
{
    conn.Open();
    using (var comm = new SqlCommand("FooBarProcedure", conn) { CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure }) 
    {
         comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@FooBar", "shizzle"));
         comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

(Source stored procedures: [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1260961/1829773))

**Multi threading**: The safest way to use multi threading and SQL connections is to always close and dispose your connection object. It's the behavior the SqlConnection was designed for. (Source: [Answer John Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23942409/1829773))

Comment: You are a great man. In this Answer I have to get knowledge more than that my entire semester knowledge. Thank You man. But I have some problems. 1) If Use Stored Procedures to handle CRUD, It's good or bad ? 2) If this connection pooling method will help me at multi threading?

Answer (score 1):

Best practice is make a common DBHelper class and create CRUD methods into that class.
I am adding code snippet.This may help you.

**web.config**

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="mssqltips"
         connectionString="data source=localhost;initial catalog=mssqltips;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

---

**DBHelper.cs**

```
//Opening Connection
public SqlConnection GetConnection(string connectionName)
{
  string cnstr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[connectionName].ConnectionString;
  SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(cnstr);
  cn.Open();
  return cn;
}
//for select 
public DataSet ExecuteQuery(
  string connectionName,
  string storedProcName,
  Dictionary<string, sqlparameter=""> procParameters
)
{
  DataSet ds = new DataSet();
  using(SqlConnection cn = GetConnection(connectionName))
  {
      using(SqlCommand cmd = cn.CreateCommand())
      {
          cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
          cmd.CommandText = storedProcName;
          // assign parameters passed in to the command
          foreach (var procParameter in procParameters)
          {
            cmd.Parameters.Add(procParameter.Value);
          }
          using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
          {
            da.Fill(ds);
          }
      }
 }
 return ds;
}

//for insert,update,delete

public int ExecuteCommand(
  string connectionName,
  string storedProcName,
  Dictionary<string, SqlParameter> procParameters
)
{
  int rc;
  using (SqlConnection cn = GetConnection(connectionName))
  {
    // create a SQL command to execute the stored procedure
    using (SqlCommand cmd = cn.CreateCommand())
    {
      cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
      cmd.CommandText = storedProcName;
      // assign parameters passed in to the command
      foreach (var procParameter in procParameters)
      {
        cmd.Parameters.Add(procParameter.Value);
      }
      rc = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
  }
  return rc;
}
```

Comment: Having a public method returning an open SqlConnection is hardly best practice...

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to dispose context every time you can create repository class and inject SqlConnection inside.

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=MYDB"))  
{  
    repository.SetConnection(connection);
    var values = repository.GetSomething();
}
```

And Create Class:

```
public Class Repository
{
   private SqlConnection _connection {get; set;}

   public void SetConnection(SetConnection connection)
   {
        _connection = connection;
   }

   public string GetSomething()
   {
       _connection.Open();
       //do stuff with _connection
       _connection.Close();
   }
}
```

**Anyway I recommend you to read about ORM's (Entity Framework or Dapper) and SQL injection attack.**

Comment: Is this repository meant to be a singleton or per-dependency? Is it thread-safe?

Comment: that is nice, but if it is not just a university project read about SQL injection attack first. @Vishal Pawar proposed verry good solution, where he prepares data via stored procedure and that is a good way to get something from db. He also gets connection string from web.config, what is also a good thing (better than my solution)

Comment: @John that is my answer, not a production code :) For a WinForm singleton repository should indeed be a good option

Comment: My point is that this will fail in a multi-threaded environment. It being a WinForms application doesn't mean that it isn't a multi-threaded environment.

Comment: @John yes, injecting disposable things has that disadvantage. However, you will have to create a specific stored procedure anyway and get stuff directly from there. If you want to get data from many repositories at one time you need more complexed architecture of entire application. There is a limit of 2 API calls

Comment: But parallel calls to your single `GetSomething()` method could also cause the application to fail on the basis that you could either try to [open a connection that's already open](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.open(v=vs.110).aspx), or close a connection after `_connection.Open();` has been called by another thread and before `// do stuff with connection` has been executed by another thread. Stored procedures won't help you here.

Comment: @Arkadiusz this just a University project and there are some multi-threadings and also want to get data from many table at once. what is the best way to do connectivity ?

Comment: we are working on a resource, it is not thread safe indeed. If you use repository by many threads, then yes it will fail. My point was we are talking about WinForm so I do not expect any attempts of getting data from db anyway. To secure it he can just block async button (button not the window) and that will no longer be a problem. Otherwise we can add ReaderWriterLockSlim or something.